# отсутствует оператор, соответствующий этим операндам типы операндов: std::string = System::String ^

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

Проблема в том, что я не могу передать в строку значение из textBox1.

```
string InQ;
InQ = textBox1->Text->ToString();
```

Comment: А зачем вы это делаете? У вас есть тип `System::String ^` - вот с ним и работайте.

Comment: Я бы даже больше сказал. У вас есть c# вот на нём и пишите. Серьёзно.

Comment: Вот здесь есть ответ на этот вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1300903/7690561